# Segment bone fractures and reduce them virtually (for 3D printing)

Tags: modeling, workflow, 3d-printing

[image: Fractured bones - before]

[image: Fractued bones after]
After importing an STL model of DICOM images into Blender, is it possible to select the fractured bones individually (segment each bone) as shown in the attached pictures to then virtually reduce (replace) the fractured bones into position ?
I'm new to this. Is it possible to "paint" on the fractured bones in the 3D reconstruction to select it?
Should I do this with another software instead ?
My goal is to 3D print the reduced fractures.
Any instruction that can pointed out to me to perform this task ?

Thanks for your constructive input!

Comment: so, you have an STL model, and want to select the individual pieces to assemble the skull? you can select separated meshes by pressing L in edit mode, or you can paint with the C key tough looking at those screenshots that might take a while if your model has a lot of resolution.

If you could clarify in simpler terms what you want I could better help, as I'm not very familiar with DICOM images or what a reduced fracture is.

Comment: From the medical radiology system (which deals with DICOMs), I'm able to export an STL or OBJ file with the skull (with triangular polys).

Comment: In Blender, I would like to select all the broken bone parts individually (like in the first image), and manually reposition them in there right position like in the second image. An analogy would be fixing digitally a broken flower pot. 
From my neophyte point a view, an easy way to select a broken bone fragment would be to select it on the 3D view by painting on its surface and then cutting out that surface/volume.

Comment: The problem I have is that I can't find instructions on how to just do this task without taking extensive tutorials on modeling (which I don't do) ;-)

Comment: ah I think I understand now, I didn't even notice the difference between the two images! this looks like a modellers nightmare, not sure how your mesh looks like, if each part is a different mesh, as in, no vertices interconnecting the pieces you can go into edit mode, and select a whole piece by pressing L over it, additionally unselect pieces by pressing shift L over them. If they are connected you can paint with a radial brush by pressing C and scale the brush with the mouse wheel. If your mesh is as dense as the one in the example manual paint looks like a death sentence.

Comment: Thanks for your input Firewill.
I'm currently having issues with the amount of vertices at this moment. Even Meshmixer crashes when I try to decimate the model. I'll try to resolve that issue and get back to your instructions. Thanks!